# How to return false from traverse function as well as from inner traverse function to stop the traverse and also need unit test for this?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, recursion, ts-jest

//a user will call the traverse function like this for example stop the traversal when item found

```
let foundItem: IGXA.TAnyItem | undefined;
traverse([...], item => {
  if (item.ID === "test") {
     foundItem = item;
     return false
  }
})
```

/**
* Calls the callback for every direct and deep child item in the IGXA item list.
*
*
* @param {TItems} items
* @param {(item: TAnyItem) => void} cb
*/

```
export const traverse = (
    items: TItems,
    cb: (item: TAnyItem) => void | false,
) => {
    for (const item of items) {
        cb(item);

        if (
            item.Type === EItemType.Folder ||
            item.Type === EItemType.MultiArticle
        ) {
            traverse(item.SubItems, cb);
        }
    }
};
```

//unit test for the above function items is the array we passed to traverse
describe("traverse", () => {

```
it("calls the callback for every item", () => {
        const items: TItems = [
            {
                ID: "folder",
                Type: EItemType.Folder,
                SubItems: [
                    {
                        ID: "folder_1",
                        Type: EItemType.Folder,
                        SubItems: [
                            {
                                ID: "article",
                                Type: EItemType.ArticleGfx,
                                Caption: {},
                            },
                        ],
                        Caption: {},
                    },
                ],
                Caption: {},
            },
            {
                ID: "multiarticle",
                Type: EItemType.MultiArticle,
                Caption: {},
                MultiArticleId: "",
                SubItems: [
                    {
                        ID: "article2",
                        Type: EItemType.ArticleGfx,
                        Caption: {},
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                ID: "article3",
                Type: EItemType.ArticleGfx,
                Caption: {},
            },
        ];

        const cb = jest.fn();

        traverse(items, cb);

        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(6);
        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledWith(items[items.length - 1]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generators are a perfect fit for this -

```js
function* traverse (t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      for (const v of t) 
        yield *traverse(v)
      break
    case Object:
      yield t
      yield *traverse(t?.SubItems)
      break
  }
}
```

**Q:** *"How to return false from traverse function as well as from inner traverse function to stop the traverse?"*

**A:** Generators are pauseable and cancellable so you can easily stop iteration -

```js
function findById (graph, id) {
  for (const node in traverse(graph))
    if (node.ID === id)
      return node // <- return stops iteration and stops the generator
}

console.log(findById(TItems, "folder_1"))
```

```js
{
  ID: "folder_1",
  Type: EItemType.Folder,
  SubItems: [
      {
          ID: "article",
          Type: EItemType.ArticleGfx,
          Caption: {},
      },
  ],
  Caption: {},
}
```

**Q:** *"...and also need unit test for this?"*

**A:** Make a simple graph as the test input -

```js
const mygraph = [
  {
    id: 1,
    SubItems: [
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 3 }
    ]
  },
  { id: 4 },
  {
    id: 5,
    SubItems: [
      {
        id: 6,
        SubItems: [ { id: 7 } ]
      },
      { id: 8 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then write some simple tests -

```js
it("traverse should visit all of the nodes", _ => {
  const ids = Array.from(traverse(mygraph), node => node.id)
  assert.strictEqual(ids, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
})

it("findById should find a node", _ => {
  const match = findById(mygraph, 6)
  assert.strictEqual(match.id, 6)
  assert.strictEqual(match.SubItems.length, 1)
})

it("findById should return undefined for unmatched id", _ => {
  const match = findById(mygraph, 99)
  assert.strictEqual(match, undefined)
})
```

**Q:** *"thanks for u detailed answer but i need a callback version too? how to achieve it"*

**A:** rewrite `traverse` and implement your own `yield` which passes a `resume` control to the caller -

```js
function traverse (t, yield, resume = () => void 0) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      if (empty(t))
        return resume()
      else
        return traverse(head(t), yield, _ => traverse(tail(t), yield, resume))
    case Object:
      return yield(t, _ => traverse(t?.SubItems, yield) || resume())
  }
}
```

This depends on a few helpers, `empty`, `head` and `tail`. These aren't necessary but keep the code in `traverse` a bit cleaner and easier to read -

```js
const head = t => t[0]
const tail = t => t.slice(1)
const empty = t => t.length < 1
```

Here's `findById`. Traversal will only continue if `resume` is called -

```js
function findById (graph, id) {
  let found = undefined
  traverse(graph, (node, resume) =>
    node.id === id ? (found = node) : resume()
  )
  return found
}

console.log(findById(mygraph, 6))
```

```js
{ id: 6, SubItems: [ { id: 7 } ] }
```

Another difference is callback-based `traverse` cannot plug directly into `Array.from`. To build an array of all visited nodes, we can `push` to an array in each callback and unconditionally `resume` -

```js
function getIds (t) {
  const r = []
  traverse(t, (node, resume) =>
    r.push(node.id) && resume()
  )
  return r
}

console.log(getIds(mygraph))
```

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

For this version, you may wish to implement another unit test that verifies traversal is lazy -

```js
it("should stop traversal if resume is not called", _ => {
  const input = [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ]
  const actual = []
  traverse(input, (node, resume) => {
    actual.push(node.id)
    // do not resume()
  })
  assert.strictEqual(actual, [1], "should only contain the first item")
})
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the the program in your own browser -

```js
const head = t => t[0]
const tail = t => t.slice(1)
const empty = t => t.length < 1

function traverse (t, yield, resume = () => void 0) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      if (empty(t))
        return resume()
      else
        return traverse(head(t), yield, _ => traverse(tail(t), yield, resume))
    case Object:
      return yield(t, _ => traverse(t?.SubItems, yield) || resume())
  }
}

function getIds (graph) {
  const r = []
  traverse(graph, (node, resume) =>
    r.push(node.id) && resume()
  )
  return r
}

function findById (graph, id) {
  let found = undefined
  traverse(graph, (node, resume) =>
    node.id === id ? (found = node) : resume()
  )
  return found
}

const mygraph = 
  [{id:1,SubItems:[{id:2},{id:3}]},{id:4},{id:5,SubItems:[{id:6,SubItems:[{id:7}]},{id:8}]}]

console.log(JSON.stringify(getIds(mygraph)))
console.log(findById(mygraph, 6))
```

Comment: thanks for u detailed answer but i need a callback version too? how to achieve it

Comment: @Jahangirkhan I updated my answer in reply to your comment. Let me know if you have questions :D